# How can I use C-Go bindings in a different module/directory than the one I built them in?

Tags: c, go, compiler-errors, binding

I'm using [these](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/go-skynet/go-llama.cpp) bindings.

As per the docs, I

```
git clone --recurse-submodules https://github.com/go-skynet/go-llama.cpp
cd go-llama.cpp
make libbinding.a
```

and then running the example script, or any other script in a sub direcotory of go-llama.cpp works just fine with a command structured like:

```
LIBRARY_PATH=$PWD C_INCLUDE_PATH=$PWD go run ./examples -m "/model/path/here" -t 14
```

However, I run into problems trying to use these bindings from a different dir.
Say I have the following project layout:

```
ParentDir \
--- go-llama.cpp \
--- --- <go-llama.cpp contents>
--- project \
--- --- <Go code which references bindings>
```

If I try to run code in the project dir, I get a compilation error, common.h can't be found.
I've messed around with changing the compiler flags (which i suspect you have to do) like =$PWD to =$(pwd)../go-llama.cpp, and absolute ~/tes/go-llama.cpp, etc.

I think my compiler flags are fine, because I'm able to compile when testing with an even-more-nested dir within go-llama.cpp if I change the flags to point to the main go-llama.cpp dir from the relative location deep within the dirs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is because you're not referencing `github.com/go-skynet/go-llama.cpp` from the path you cloned – the go tool has downloaded the package into `$GOPATH/pkg/mod` but not done the `--recurse-submodules` thing when it did that.

You can see the path being used for that module by running the following command from your project:

```
go list -m -f '{{.Dir}}' github.com/go-skynet/go-llama.cpp
```

That should show something like

```
$GOPATH/pkg/mod/github.com/go-skynet/go-llama.cpp@v0.0.0-20230509080828-f4d26f43f1d3
```

If you look in that directory, you'll see the `llama.cpp` directory (and `examples` directory under it) are not there.

You can edit your project `go.mod` to reference your locally-cloned copy of the `go-llama.cpp` repo by running the following command from your project directory:

```
go mod edit -replace=github.com/go-skynet/go-llama.cpp=../go-llama.cpp/
```

I haven't tried running as I haven't downloaded a model, but (after running that `go mod edit` command) I'm able to successfully build the code using just:

```
go build
```

HTH.